# I am trying to get a response from an API using Python using requests package

Tags: python-2.7, api, unix, python-requests, response

I am using requests package.

I was provided with an authorization key and a p12 file. Using the p12 file I have generated `cert.pem` and `key.pem` (without `parsephrase` -which eliminates manual entry of the password) using the below commands in the Unix server.

I am passing the below code which is working fine in my local machine using cmd or IDE, but I am facing issues when I run it on the Unix server

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out certz.pem -in CN=32927_datahub.p12
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out keyz.pem -in CN=32927_datahub.p12
openssl rsa -in keyz.pem -out npkeyz.pem

url = "https://enterprise.*****.com/api/mdm/devices/search?lgid=12174"

auth= "CMSURL`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"

head = {'AW-Tenant-Code':"u0WkQqShvxht0GLvZ43ux8jqOrp/mNgVFWhceh7iQz0=",'Content-Type':"application/json",'Authorization':auth}
r = requests.get(url, headers=head, cert=('D:\\DEP3\\certz.pem','D:\\DEP3\\npkeyz.pem'),verify=True)
file=open("D:\\VMWARE_DAT\\data\\b2b\\land\VMWARE\\JSON\\final.json",'w+')
print(r.json())
#print(json.dump(r.json(),file,indent=4))
```

The above code is working fine and I am getting the response on my local using cmd shell.

I am facing errors when I try to tun the same code in Unix environment, where I have generated the cert and key `.pem` files

[image]

Comment: i am using the unix locations for the certificate files in the code when running in unix server

Comment: Can you provide exception as text instead of the image? What kind of unix platform ? Do the versions of python and packages match?

Comment: Did you solve this?